# Add additional field to existing column in web page

Tags: asp.net

All,

Below is is my exist code for my ASPX web page.  I would like to add additional field "FLOOR_LOC" to the existing column on the second line.  The result will look some like this...

**Head Quarter**
**Main Floor South**

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PHYS_LOC" HeaderText="Phys Loc" SortExpression="PHYS_LOC">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
        </asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine multiple fields into a single column, then you may want to consider using a [`TemplateField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield(v=vs.110).aspx), which is designed for handling this type of behavior :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phys Loc" SortExpression="PHYS_LOC">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="PHYS_LOC" runat="server" Text='<%#= Bind("PHYS_LOC") %>'></asp:Label>
      <br />
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FLOOR_LOC") %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>      
</asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: Thanks Rion, could you check your code again.  I pasted your code in and  I got the following error.....  Validation (ASP.NET:  Atribute 'DataField' is not a valid attribute of element 'TemplateField'

Comment: I think that was more of a copy-paste error. The `DataField` is generally used for the previous `BoundField` elements that you were using it. `HeaderText` and `SortExpression` should still be valid, so just try removing `DataField` entirely.